# How to get Dropbox directory by using ruby?

Tags: ruby, dropbox

I want to get Dropbox directory like "c:\Users\foo\Dropbox" or "/Users/foo/Dropbox" by using ruby.

Is there a simple way to do it?

Comment: `File.expand_path(File.join('~', 'Dropbox'))` ?

Comment: Thanks @falsetru, but I want to get the directory even if user changed Dropbox directory. I should have written my example precisely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newer versions of the Dropbox client write a file that contains the path(s) to the Dropbox folder(s) that you can read for this purpose. You can find more information here:

https://www.dropbox.com/help/4584

In short, you can read that info.json file and parse the contents as JSON to retrieve the Dropbox folder path(s).

Answer (score 1):

From the [dropbox API page](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/ruby):

```
# Install this the SDK with "gem install dropbox-sdk"
require 'dropbox_sdk'

# Get your app key and secret from the Dropbox developer website
APP_KEY = 'INSERT_APP_KEY'
APP_SECRET = 'INSERT_APP_SECRET'

flow = DropboxOAuth2FlowNoRedirect.new(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET)
authorize_url = flow.start()

# Have the user sign in and authorize this app
puts '1. Go to: ' + authorize_url
puts '2. Click "Allow" (you might have to log in first)'
puts '3. Copy the authorization code'
print 'Enter the authorization code here: '
code = gets.strip

# This will fail if the user gave us an invalid authorization code
access_token, user_id = flow.finish(code)

client = DropboxClient.new(access_token)
puts "linked account:", client.account_info().inspect

file = open('working-draft.txt')
response = client.put_file('/magnum-opus.txt', file)
puts "uploaded:", response.inspect

root_metadata = client.metadata('/')
puts "metadata:", root_metadata.inspect
```

At this stage, you could do worse than invoke client.get_file for every root_metadata['contents'] where root_metadata['contents']['is_dir'] is false. How best to do this, is left as an exercise for OP.

Comment: Thanks for your information, but I don't want to let user do authorize process only to find the Dropbox directory.

Comment: I don't think this is a possiblity, @Tetsu, but I'd be delighted to be proven wrong.